# Setting iframe height to 100% seems to overflow containing div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple HTML page with a sidebar floated to the left and all content to the right. In the main content area I have an `<iframe>`. However, when I use CSS to set the height of the frame to 100% it seems to overflow the containing `div` for some reason, resulting in a small amount of white-space after my content.

Here is **my HTML content**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe id="contentFrame"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is **my CSS**:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#contentFrame {       
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
}
```

(**NOTE**: Before anybody asks, `#container { position: absolute }` is necessary for layout reasons; I can't change that.)

You can see it 'working' on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9q7yp/

The aim is to get rid of the white band along the bottom of the page (i.e. there shouldn't be a vertical scroll-bar in the result). If I set `overflow: hidden` for `#content` then the problem goes away. I'm happy to do this if necessary, but I can't for the life of me work out why it doesn't work without this. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to add

```
display:block;
```

to the `iframe`. http://jsfiddle.net/9q7yp/14/

---

**Edit**:

Well, it turns out there's a better solution (both in practice and in understanding what's going on):

Add

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

to `iframe#contentFrame`. http://jsfiddle.net/9q7yp/17/

`<iframe>`, as an *inline* element, has the initial value of `vertical-align:baseline`, but a `height:100%` inline element will "push" the base line a few pixels lower (because initially the baseline is a few pixels higher from the bottom),

so the parent `DIV` is thinking "well content will be 2 pixels lower, I need to make room for that".

You can see this effect in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWKkR/1/) (check your browser console and pay attention to the `bottom` property of both `ClientRect` object).

Comment: Nicely done :-)  Now, if you can explain what's going on I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Excellent, comprehensive description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin:0` to body

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto; 
}
```

WORKING **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uwilod/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks. That's strange though; your demo seems to work, but if I apply it to my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tRhCC/1/) it doesn't. Any idea why?  ...also the jsbin live preview doesn't work either: http://jsbin.com/uwilod/4

Comment: I dont have access to jsfiddle as my network admin blocks some of the js files from jsfiddle m sorry ;) but if you can create it on any other website like jsbin etc .. may b I can try

Comment: did you look at the jsbin link I included? The problem is still there.

Comment: add `#contentFrame {position: absolute; }`in your contentFrame CSS. reason for that is not clear to me. will find out and when I will get time.

Comment: @Champ Using `position:absolute` will "float" the `iframe` out of `div` when calculating size, that means `div#content` is now actually 0px in content height. You can see this if you remove the `height:100%` in `div#content`. That's why the scrollbar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0` to your `html, body {}` section.

Answer (score 0):

..................***[.demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9q7yp/10/)***

Hi now give to `overflow:hidden;` of this id `#content`

as like this

```
#content{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9q7yp/10/)***

Comment: Thanks, but you'll note that in the original text of my question I mentioned I've already tried that and it works. However, I want to know why it's necessary (i.e. why is the iframe overflowing the div?).